# EWS GetItems response items sort order

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I use Exchange 2010 Web Services SDK. And I need to retrieve items using method GetItem.

For example:

```cs
var getItemTypes = new GetItemType();
getItemTypes.ItemIds = ids;
getItemTypes.ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType()
{
    BodyType = BodyTypeResponseType.Best,
    BodyTypeSpecified = true,
    BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties,
    IncludeMimeContent = true,
    IncludeMimeContentSpecified = true
};

GetItemResponseType getItemResponse = esb.GetItem(getItemTypes);
```

And I want to know if items in getItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items array are strongly corresponds to "ids" array.

The problem is that it is not always possible to retrieve the item ID from response.

Does anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a batch EWS request the Exchange Server will respond in the order that the request was submitted. Eg if you had the Id's for 4 items and the Id at element 2 in that collection you using when submitting was removed from the folder so that Id was no longer valid in the responses you get back the ResponseMessage in the second element of the responsecollection will be an error indicating that the Item no longer exists in the Store. (The documentation is a little sketchy around the proxy code but if you want to read a good book on this stuff check out Inside exchange web services which has better explanations ).

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I also think that it is almost certainly working like you described. But I'm trying to find some proof from the respected source.